# Get loading time in video tag html5

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to get video tag html5 loading time.if on first 5 sec video is not play than page is redirect to another link

Here My code :

```
<body  onLoad="document.getElementById('myVideo').play();document.getElementById('myVideo').width=swidth;document.getElementById('myVideo').height=sheight;" style="background-color:#000;text-align:center;">
<video    id="myVideo">
<source src="<?php echo $this->baseUrl ?>/xsn/XSun.webm" type="audio/webm" />
<source src="<?php echo $this->baseUrl ?>/xsn/XSun.mp4" codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2" type="audio/mpeg">
<source src="<?php echo $this->baseUrl ?>/xsn/XSun.ogv" type="audio/ogg">
</video>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){   
   $("#myVideo").bind('ended', function(){
      location.href="<?php echo $this->baseUrl ?>";   
   }); 
  });
</script>
```

Please help

Thanks 
Amit Anand

Comment: any one can help me with this problem

Comment: Thanks ShaunaK D :) and plz help me

Comment: `body onload` and `$.ready()` generally uncompatible: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: MIchael Liach  , plz explain ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it. Create a Javascript timeout to redirect after 5 seconds, and attach an event handler to the `playing` media event to clear the timeout. This will make it so that if the video starts playing within the 5 second timeout the redirect will not occur.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var video = $('#myVideo');
    var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        location.href = "http:// whatever";
    }, 5000);

    video.bind('playing', function() {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
    });

    video.get(0).play();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

// comments are too short

According to jQuery documentation, your code should be at least:

```
<body style="background-color:#000;text-align:center;">
<video id="myVideo">
<source src="<?php echo $this->baseUrl ?>/xsn/XSun.webm" type="audio/webm" />
<source src="<?php echo $this->baseUrl ?>/xsn/XSun.mp4" codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2" type="audio/mpeg">
<source src="<?php echo $this->baseUrl ?>/xsn/XSun.ogv" type="audio/ogg">
</video>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    // swidth and sheight are global variables ?
    document.getElementById('myVideo').width=swidth;
    document.getElementById('myVideo').height=sheight;
    document.getElementById('myVideo').play();

   $("#myVideo").bind('ended', function(){
      location.href="<?php echo $this->baseUrl ?>";   
   }); 
  });
</script>
```

Comment: You can share one thing , how to possible to get video loading time .i want to check video loading time ,when in 5 sec video is not playing than page is redirect to another page.that it.